# How to change expect text in dart test

Tags: dart, testing, dart-test

Is there a possibility to change the text that is printed if a dart `expect` fails?

It works fine with primitives but working with lists of objects makes it really hard to find the difference.

**UPDATE**

Testing library uses `toString()` method to display the value diffs in the test result. I am using freezed so by default this will just dump all the object properties.
A solution is to implement a custom `toString` in your class to alter how objects are displayed in test result.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `reason` parameter to [`expect`](https://pub.dev/documentation/test_api/latest/expect/expect.html):

```dart
import 'package:test/test.dart';

void main() {
  test('Example', () {
    var data = ['duck', 'duck', 'goose'];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
      expect(data[i], 'duck', reason: 'Failed on iteration $i');
    }
  });
}
```

prints:

```
00:00 +0 -1: Example [E]

  Expected: 'duck'
    Actual: 'goose'
     Which: is different.
            Expected: duck
              Actual: goose
                      ^
             Differ at offset 0
  Failed on iteration 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but the problem still persists because in your example you have used just strings. The problem becomes more clear to when testing a stream that emits multiple events with `emits` or `emitsInOrder` where each event is a list of 10 items each being an object with around 10 properties including nested objects.

Comment: @CodeSpirit The `String` part is not relevant; what's relevant is that this example just does a simple iteration over a list.  It would help if you gave a more specific example of the case you're trying to handle and what kind of message you want.